# What does the arrow operator, '->', do in Java?

Tags: java, java-8

While hunting through some code I came across the arrow operator, what exactly does it do? I thought Java did not have an arrow operator.

```
return (Collection<Car>) CollectionUtils.select(listOfCars, (arg0) -> {
        return Car.SEDAN == ((Car)arg0).getStyle();
});
```

***Details**: Java 6, Apache Commons Collection, IntelliJ 12*

***Update/Answer:** It turns out that IntelliJ 12 supports Java 8, which supports lambdas, and is "folding" Predicates and displaying them as lambdas. Below is the "un-folded" code.*

```
return (Collection<Car>) CollectionUtils.select(listOfCars, new Predicate() {
    public boolean evaluate(Object arg0) {
        return Car.SEDAN == ((Car)arg0).getStyle();
    }
});
```

Comment: Note that the exact scenario is IntelliJ _rendering_ the existing code as a lambda expression to make it easier to read.   The actual code is not a lambda expression.

Answer (score 216, accepted):

That's part of the syntax of the new lambda expressions, to be introduced in Java 8. There are a couple of online tutorials to get the hang of it, here's a [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) to one. Basically, the `->` separates the parameters (left-side) from the implementation (right side).

The general syntax for using lambda expressions is

`(Parameters) -> { Body }` where the `->` separates parameters and lambda expression body.

The parameters are enclosed in parentheses which is the same way as for methods and the lambda expression body is a block of code enclosed in braces.

Comment: The OP using JDK 6, so this is really just IntelliJ folding code as per @antonm answer below

Comment: @SeanLandsman OP might be using Java 6, but in the question he states that he came across that code elsewhere. As to why IntelliJ isn't reporting an error, that's a mystery (perhaps there _is_ a Java 7 version installed somewhere in OP's system). But that's a lambda expression's syntax in Java, there's no question about it.

Comment: Do you happen to know the name of this token type?

Answer (score 83):

This one is useful as well when you want to implement a functional interface

```java
Runnable r = ()-> System.out.print("Run method");
```

is equivalent to

```java
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.print("Run method");
        }
};
```

Comment: why is this feature provided?

Comment: @Akaisteph7 when you do not want to define a method because you find that only one caller is ever going to call that method. In those cases it makes sense to NOT define the method in a separate place rather pass in the body of the method, read about anonymous method followed by lambda.

Comment: How can i see that specifically run() method was overwritten ?

Comment: @Pirks It depends on the class, in this case Runnable()

Comment: Runnable contains other methods for overwriting. How specifically run() was chosen?

Comment: @Pirks - one can only use that on Interfaces that has only 1 method,

Comment: @Akaisteph7 One nice thing this feature does is clean up code when you add events in Swing or JavaFx.  I think it's much easier to read this way.

Answer (score 35):

I believe, this arrow exists because of your IDE. IntelliJ IDEA does such thing with some code. This is called code folding. You can click at the arrow to expand it.

Comment: @DavidConrad No, it's not wrong. IntelliJ does indeed fold inline implementations of functional interfaces to look like lambdas.

Comment: Look at the question:
"Details: Java 6, Apache Commons Collection, IntelliJ 12"
Lambda in java 6 ???

Answer (score 15):

It's a lambda expression.

It means that, from the listOfCars, arg0 is one of the items of that list.
With that item he is going to do, hence the ->, whatever is inside of the brackets.

In this example, he's going to return a list of cars that fit the condition

```
Car.SEDAN == ((Car)arg0).getStyle();
```

Answer (score 7):

New Operator **for lambda expression added in java 8**

Lambda expression is the **short way of method writing.**
 
It is indirectly used to implement [functional interface](https://stacktraceguru.com/java-8-functional-interface?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=post)

**Primary Syntax : (parameters) -> { statements; }**

There are some basic [rules for effective lambda expressions writting](https://stacktraceguru.com/java-lambda-expression?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=post#thinksToKnowAboutLambda) which you should konw.

Answer (score 1):

The arrow operator is used to create lambda expressions, linking/separating parameters with the lambda body.
syntax: (parameters) -> {expression};
It is also an efficient way of implementing functional interfaces like onClickListeners in java.