# What is the "->" operator in Java? Is it even an operator?

Tags: java, syntax

I saw this bit of code on Oracle's java documentation page for  [java.util.stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)

```
int sum = widgets.stream()
                  .filter(b -> b.getColor() == RED)
                  .mapToInt(b -> b.getWeight())
                  .sum();
```

My question - what does "b -> b.getColor()" mean? What is the -> operator?

Comment: @StephenC It's listed in the [operators section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.12) of the JLS though... And they confirm it in [15.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.2) : *"The lowest precedence operator is the arrow of a lambda expression (->), followed by the assignment operators."*.

Comment: I question closing this question as a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15146052/what-does-the-arrow-operator-do-in-java.  It turns out that in *that* case, the OP was seeing IDE code folding ... in Java 6 source code!

Answer (score 5):

The `->` is part of a *lambda expression*. These were introduced in Java 8, and you can read more about them in [The Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html). In short, a lambda expression can replace an anonymous class if you are implementing an interface that contains only one method.

Also, the syntax of the lambda expression is described in detail in the [JLS §15.27](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27):

> A lambda expression is like a method: it provides a list of formal parameters and a body - an expression or block - expressed in terms of those parameters.
>   LambdaExpression:
>   *LambdaParameters -> LambdaBody*

```
Examples:  
() -> {}                // No parameters; result is void  
() -> 42                // No parameters, expression body
() -> {                 // Complex block body with returns
  if (true) return 12;
  else {
    int result = 15;
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
      result *= i;
    return result;
  }
} 
(int x) -> x+1          // Single declared-type parameter
```

Comment: Could you add a brief explanation of what a lambda function is, in case those links ever go bad?