# Unknown syntax in Java Code

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, rest, spring-boot

I am going through Building REST Services with Spring Tutorial at https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/

And I am stuck at a point. In the `class Application`, there is this spooky piece of code:

```
return (evt) -> Arrays.asList(
"jhoeller,dsyer,pwebb,ogierke,rwinch,mfisher,mpollack,jlong".split(","))
.forEach(
a -> {
Account account = accountRepository.save(new Account(a,
"password"));
bookmarkRepository.save(new Bookmark(account,
"http://bookmark.com/1/" + a, "A description"));
bookmarkRepository.save(new Bookmark(account,
"http://bookmark.com/2/" + a, "A description"));
});
```

I seriously have no idea whats going on there. From where `evt` came, there is no relevant import. And what does `->` operator do in Java. I have never used this operator in Java. Is there any operator as such, first of all?

Even my eclipse says the same thing that

> evt cannot be resolved to a variable

Nobody seems to ask similar question on internet, I searched a lot. Am I missing something?

Comment: This is Java 8 syntax (a lambda expression, i.e. sort of an anonymous function), and from your descriptions you seem not to be familiar with Java 8. You are probably still running Java 7 or older.

Comment: This looks like Java lambda notation from Java 8.  You can see if there is a Java 7 version of the tutorial, or here is oracles guide to lambdas https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Comment: @ tobias_k Ok, I see. Thanks for that info, and what about evt. Does that also comes under that new syntax definition. I mean, without defining an identifier, can we use them like this? Any links?

Comment: Yes, it is part of the new notation, the type for evt will be inferred by the compiler.  If you switch your eclipse project to using JDK 8, it should have no problems with the above code, in theory at least

Comment: `evt` is defined _within_ the lambda expression. That expression, `evt -> Arrays.asList(...)` is roughly equivalent to `new Function() {public List apply(Event evt) {return Arrays.asList(...)}}`

Comment: `evt` is the parameter being passed into the lambda function. [Here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html) is some info on lambda functions in java. Also type `java -version` into your console to find java version (should be at least `1.8`  to support lambda)

Comment: @Gavin Ok. I got it. These are something like Python lambdas. Correct? But what about Eclipse. My project is using jdk1.8.0_92. Then why it is showing the error?

Comment: @AadishPatodi er, I don't know Python, but given the name, i am going to say yes, probably.  Cant really help with eclipse, I haven't used it for years. tobias_k gives a much better answer below.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the arrow operator, '->', do in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15146052/what-does-the-arrow-operator-do-in-java)

Comment: That code is especially spooky because of the *very* bad indentations (not having any indentations is very bad).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is Java 8 syntax (a lambda expression, i.e. sort of an anonymous function), and from your descriptions you seem not to be familiar with Java 8. You are probably still running Java 7 or older. You can check your Java version using the `java -version` command.

About `evt`: It is defined *within* the lambda expression, which is roughly equivalent to this:

```
new Consumer<Event>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(Event evt) {
        for (String a: Arrays.asList("jhoeller,dsyer,pwebb,ogierke,rwinch,mfisher,mpollack,jlong".split(",")) {
            Account account = accountRepository.save(new Account(a,
                    "password"));
            bookmarkRepository.save(new Bookmark(account,
                    "http://bookmark.com/1/" + a, "A description"));
            bookmarkRepository.save(new Bookmark(account,
                    "http://bookmark.com/2/" + a, "A description"));
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to run that code, you will have to download and install a new Version of Java. If you are already using Java 8, then you probably have to configure your system properly.

From your comments I gather that you are using Eclipse. First, you have to use an Eclipse that can *handle* Java 8 (Luna or newer), then select the correct JDK in Eclipse (Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs), and also set the source compatibility level of your project to Java 8 (Project's Properties -> Java Compiler -> JDK Compliance).

Comment: Thanks, I was using Kepler and hence Java 8 was not being supported.

Comment: @AadishPatodi There is also an upgrade for Kepler for enabling Java 8 support, but given that it's three years old now, I think it's time to move on. ;-)