# Cant understand IntFunction behaviour

Tags: java, lambda

I was creating a Lambda Expression for `IntFunction` present in `java.util.function` package provided in Java 8.

When I am writing expression like below, its working fine:

```
int i = 10;
IntFunction<Employee> intFunction = (i) -> new Employee(i, "name");
```

But when I write below expression its showing compile time error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to IntFunction<Employee>`:

```
IntFunction<Employee> intFunction = (10) -> new Employee(10, "name");
```

Is it necessary to pass a declared variable as input to Lambda Expression. Can't we pass directly value of the type expected by Lambda Expression??

Comment: Can you declare a method like this: `int add(10,20) { return 30;}` ?

Comment: No its not possible. So its same here ??

Comment: Right!! it is a compiled form to be used for various values.

Comment: Okay, means it is not allowing so that later can be used for different value otherwise it is stuck with that one value.

Comment: Thanks for clearing the concept.

Comment: Welcome. You may want to go through this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15146052/what-does-the-arrow-operator-do-in-java

Comment: @SachinSarawgi If you want check this http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html

Comment: This is also good one ;-) http://data-structure-learning.blogspot.cz/2015/07/java-lambda-intfunction-functional.html