# What does the arrow ("->") operator do in Kotlin?

Tags: operators, kotlin

Probably a little bit broad question, but the official documentation doesn't even mentioning the arrow operator (or language construct, I don't know which phrase is more accurate) as an independent entity.

The most obvious use is the when conditional statement, where it is used to assign an expression to a specific condition:

```
  val greet = when(args[0]) {
    "Appul" -> "howdy!"
    "Orang" -> "wazzup?"
    "Banan" -> "bonjur!"
    else    -> "hi!"
  }

  println(args[0] +" greets you: \""+ greet +"\"")
```

What are the other uses, and what are they do?
Is there a general meaning of the arrow operator in Kotlin?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The `->` is part of Kotlin's syntax (similar to Java's [lambda expressions syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15146052/what-does-the-arrow-operator-do-in-java)) and can be used in 3 contexts:

- `when` expressions where it separates "matching/condition" part from "result/execution" block

  ```
   val greet = when(args[0]) {
     "Apple", "Orange" -> "fruit"
     is Number -> "How many?"
     else    -> "hi!"
   }
  ```
- lambda expressions where it separates parameters from function body

  ```
    val lambda = { a:String -> "hi!" }
    items.filter { element -> element == "search"  }
  ```
- function types where it separates parameters types from result type e.g. `comparator`

  ```
    fun <T> sort(comparator:(T,T) -> Int){
    }
  ```

Details about Kotlin grammar are [in the documentation](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html) in particular:

- [functionType](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#functionType)
- [functionLiteral](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#functionLiteral)
- [whenEntry](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#whenEntry)

Comment: Probably adding the [function types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-types) example and the link to the reference might improve this answer.

Comment: And now there are 3 contexts and not just 2.

Comment: Thanks for the help and the detailed answer, guys. I'll dig into the other two.

Answer (score 25):

The `->` is a **separator**. It is special symbol used to separate code with different purposes. It can be used to:

- Separate the parameters and body of a [lambda expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#lambda-expression-syntax)

  ```
  val sum = { x: Int, y: Int -> x + y }
  ```
- Separate the parameters and return type declaration in a [function type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-types)

  ```
  (R, T) -> R
  ```
- Separate the condition and body of a [when expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression) branch

  ```
  when (x) {
      0, 1 -> print("x == 0 or x == 1")
      else -> print("otherwise")
  }
  ```

Here it is in the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/keyword-reference.html).

Comment: To me, the accepted answer didn't explain the fundamental concept that `->` is a separator. My answer was an attempt to address that. I also tried to provide examples which demonstrate that separation clearly.

Comment: Fair enough, I'm new to Kotlin myself, and did not realize that.

Answer (score 5):

From the [Kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/keyword-reference.html):

> `->`
>
> - separates the parameters and body of a [lambda expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#lambda-expression-syntax)
> - separates the parameters and return type declaration in a [function
>     type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-types)
> - separates the condition and body of a [when expression](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression) branch