# What does -> and ? operators mean in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm currently learning java and trying to understand Kotlin code but I don't understand what this expression stands for:

```
a == a -> file?.let { 
    createDataSource("aaa.xml", it)
}


 createDataSource(filename: String, outfile: File) {
     ...
     ObjectOutputStream(FileOutputStream(outfile)).use {
          it -> it.wroteObject(map)
      }}
```

Is this some sort of lambda expression? What does 'it' mean? What does operator '->' and '?' mean?
Can someone help me to translate it into java?

Comment: Did you try reading the Kotlin docs? Running through a [tutorial](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/) to learn the basic syntax?

Comment: Yes, I'm working on it, but I've stuck on this part of code, I don't understand this specific structure with file

Comment: the `->` is the same as in java. And any basic tutorial mentions the `?` operator.

Comment: For `->`, see [Higher-Order Functions and Lambdas](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html). For `it`, see [it: implicit name of a single parameter](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#it-implicit-name-of-a-single-parameter). For `?.` (note the operator is `?.` and not just `?`), see [Safe Calls](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the arrow ("->") operator do in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42646016/what-does-the-arrow-operator-do-in-kotlin)

Comment: @Slaw Perhaps you can make an Answer of your Comment so this Question can be marked as resolved.

Comment: @Basil added community answer

Answer (score 2):

As for what is exactly happening in the given code, or converting it to Java, there's not enough context for a confident answer (if somebody believes differently please feel free to edit this answer). However, you also ask about various identifiers and operators and those are explained below.

---

## `it` "Special Identifier"

See [it: implicit name of a single parameter](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#it-implicit-name-of-a-single-parameter):

> It's very common that a lambda expression has only one parameter.
>
> If the compiler can figure the signature out itself, it is allowed not to declare the only parameter and omit `->`. The parameter will be implicitly declared under the name `it`:
>
> ```
> ints.filter { it > 0 } // this literal is of type '(it: Int) -> Boolean'
> ```

**Java equivalent:** N/A.

---

## `->` Operator

- See [Lambda expression syntax](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#lambda-expression-syntax):

  > The full syntactic form of lambda expressions is as follows:
  >
  > ```
  > val sum: (Int, Int) -> Int = { x: Int, y: Int -> x + y }
  > ```
  >
  > A lambda expression is always surrounded by curly braces, parameter declarations in the full syntactic form go inside curly braces and have optional type annotations, the body goes after an `->` sign. If the inferred return type of the lambda is not `Unit`, the last (or possibly single) expression inside the lambda body is treated as the return value.
  >
  > If we leave all the optional annotations out, what's left looks like this:
  >
  > ```
  > val sum = { x, y -> x + y }
  > ```

  **Java equivalent(ish):** lambda expressions.
- And [Function types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-types):

  > Kotlin uses a family of function types like `(Int) -> String` for declarations that deal with functions: `val onClick: () -> Unit = ....`
  >
  > These types have a special notation that corresponds to the signatures of the functions, i.e. their parameters and return values:
  >
  > - All function types have a parenthesized parameter types list and a return type: `(A, B) -> C` denotes a type that represents functions taking two arguments of types `A` and `B` and returning a value of type `C`. The parameter types list may be empty, as in `() -> A`. The `Unit` return type cannot be omitted.
  >
  > [...]

  **Java equivalent:** N/A *(closest equivalent would be "functional interfaces")*.
- And [When Expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression):

  > `when` replaces the switch operator of C-like languages. In the simplest form it looks like this:
  >
  > ```
  > when (x) {
  >     1 -> print("x == 1")
  >     2 -> print("x == 2")
  >     else -> { // Note the block
  >         print("x is neither 1 nor 2")
  >     }
  > }
  > ```
  >
  > [...]
  >
  > See the [grammar for `when`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#whenExpression).

  **Java equivalent(ish?):** switch expressions *(preview feature as of Java 13)*.

---

## "`?`" Operator

Note the operator in the code in your question is actually `?.`, not just `?`. See [Safe Calls](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls):

> Your second option is the safe call operator, written `?.`:
>
> ```
> val a = "Kotlin"
> val b: String? = null
> println(b?.length)
> println(a?.length) // Unnecessary safe call
> ```
>
> This returns `b.length` if `b` is not null, and `null` otherwise. The type of this expression is `Int?`.
>
> Safe calls are useful in chains. For example, if Bob, an Employee, may be assigned to a Department (or not), that in turn may have another Employee as a department head, then to obtain the name of Bob's department head (if any), we write the following:
>
> ```
> bob?.department?.head?.name
> ```
>
> Such a chain returns `null` if any of the properties in it is null.
>
> To perform a certain operation only for non-null values, you can use the safe call operator together with `let`:
>
> ```
> val listWithNulls: List<String?> = listOf("Kotlin", null)
> for (item in listWithNulls) {
>    item?.let { println(it) } // prints Kotlin and ignores null
> }
> ```
>
> A safe call can also be placed on the left side of an assignment. Then, if one of the receivers in the safe calls chain is null, the assignment is skipped, and the expression on the right is not evaluated at all:
>
> ```
> // If either `person` or `person.department` is null, the function is not called:
> person?.department?.head = managersPool.getManager()
> ```

**Java equivalent:** N/A.