# Multithreading, reusable Runnable with caller-specific operations

Tags: java, multithreading

Given two servers, `Server1.java` and `Server2.java`. Their task is to collect some data from a client socket in the same way, then do different operations with that.

First, they both delegate each client socket connection to a new Thread to be able to handle multiple clients at the same time. As they do the same operations to collect the data, the code in the run() method of this Thread's Runnable could be the same for both servers. ..So basically they could both use the same class to create the Thread.

But: the problem is that at one place in this Runnable, the servers do different things already as another non-blocking operation, so basically a new Thread should be started from this Thread with Runnables that already differ for the servers. This single line is not the same for both servers.

And this is what leaves me helpless now how I could reuse other parts of the Runnable which is although the exact same for both servers except for one line of code.

Did I make it clear?

(One option I can think of would be to create the original thread with an argument that tells which Runnable it should call at that point but that's not a pretty thing.)

So what's the proper way of doing this? Is it at all a normal procedure I try to achieve?

---

**Code snippets:**

In `Server1.java` and `Server2.java`:

```
/* Creating a client socket every time a client connects to
 * the server and delegating its management to a new thread... */
for (; ; ) { new Thread(new DataReceiver(serverSocket.accept())).start(); }
```

In `DataReceiver.java`:

```
public class DataReceiver implements Runnable {

    private Socket clientSocket;
    private BufferedReader socketIn;

    public DataReceiver(Socket clientSocket) { /* ... */ }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // ...
        while ((inputLine = socketIn.readLine()) != null) {
            // ...
            new Thread(new ThisClassOrThatClass()).start(); //the only difference
            // ...
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: *Did I make it clear* - not entirely, you describe code too much, *show* it. *One option I can think of would be to create the original thread with an argument that tells which Runnable it should call at that point but that's not a pretty thing.* - I would disagree, that does not sound too bad. You do not have to pass in a runnable, you can pass in any object instance implementing some interface and call that interface method at the given point.

Comment: Thread class accepts Runnable *interface*, so you can implement Runnable interface for both classes server1 and server2 and create threads from them with different logic. Where is the problem?

Comment: Create an interface called something like "HandlerSupplier" which you implement two times, for one server you always return a `new ThisClass()`, for the other you always return `new ThatClass()` assuming both have a `Runnable` as super type. You can even drop the custom interface and simply use `Supplier<Runnable>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only see the option already outlined in the comments / your post with some variations:

```
for (; ; ) { new Thread(new DataReceiver(serverSocket.accept(), () -> new ThisClass())).start(); }
```

and then:

```
public class DataReceiver implements Runnable {

    private Socket clientSocket;
    private BufferedReader socketIn;
    private Supplier<Runnable> runnableSupplier;

    public DataReceiver(Socket clientSocket, Supplier<Runnable> runnableSupplier) { /* ... */ }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // ...
        while ((inputLine = socketIn.readLine()) != null) {
            // ...
            new Thread(runnableSupplier.get()).start();
            // ...
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

You can create a custom interface `Handler` with a method `getHandlerRunnable()` instead of using the already existing generic `Supplier<Runnable>`.

Alternatively you can change the logic in a minor way by not using a `getHandlerRunnable()` but simply `handleSomething(...)` and letting that method *maybe* create a new Thread and doing something.

Comment: @tom that is a lambda expression in case you did not know the term yet, previously you would have to create an anonymous class implementing the interface, it just is a lot shorter this way.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45959868/5214911) I found what it does.