# How to regroup catch finally into one method in java 8?

Tags: java, java-8

New to java 8, I would like to optimise my code bellow:

```
public Response create() {
    try{
        ...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        codeA;
    } finally {
        codeB;
    }
}

public Response update() {
    try{
        ...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        codeA;
    } finally {
        codeB;
    }
}
```

I have a lot of methods using this same way to catch exceptions and do the same finally, is that possible to replace the bellow common code by a method in java 8? So that I could optimise all my methods who use this common code.

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    codeA;
} finally {
    codeB;
}
```

Comment: It might be that this is a case for `AutoCloseable` and **try-with-resources**. For instance if in finally you call `close()` on something. JDBC benefits from try-with-resources, but also own classes implementing Autocloseable. Then there is no need for a finally part.

Comment: There are some options to achieve reusability in your code, however, it will require refactoring and other OO strategies. Similar to Joop said.

- is the codeB can be refactored?can use AutoCloseable interface? if so you can abstract the code needed to close it in a separated class and use the initialization or object reference with try-with-resource statements, removing the need of finally block.
- the codeA you can refactor to use a customized exception implementation
- Another alternative is the use of Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) to inject the code needed for exception handling.

Comment: Are you sure you want to catch and act upon general Exceptions in your `create()` and `update()` methods instead of letting them ripple through to their respective callers and so on? Meaning: How are you going to inform your caller that creation / update didn't succeed?

Comment: Inversion of Control (with lambdas or interfaces) is what you are looking for. Could be with frameworks (interceptors) or by using libraries like Spring JDBC Template. BUT I feel it is often a warning sign if you need that and the code is not always easier to follow and maintain.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Depends what you do in the `...`. You could do something like this:

```
private Response method(Supplier<Response> supplier) {
    try{
        return supplier.get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        codeA;
    } finally {
        codeB;
    }
}
```

and invoke like:

```
public Response create() { return method(() -> { ... for create }); }
public Response update() { return method(() -> { ... for update }); }
```

Comment: What's `->` doing ?

Comment: @Feelsbadman https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15146052/what-does-the-arrow-operator-do-in-java

Answer (score 8):

You could wrap your `payload` and put it to the separate method. One thing; what do you expect to return on exception catch. This time this is `null`, but probably you could provide default value.

```
public static <T> T execute(Supplier<T> payload) {
    try {
        return payload.get();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        // code A
        return null;
    } finally {
        // code B
    }
}
```

---

Client code could look like this:

```
public Response create() {
    return execute(() -> new CreateResponse());
}

public Response update() {
    return execute(() -> new UpdateResponse());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a generic solution.

```
//here describe supplier which can throw exceptions

@FunctionalInterface
public interface ThrowingSupplier<T> {
    T get() throws Exception;
}

// The wrapper
private <T> T callMethod(ThrowingSupplier<T> supplier) {
    try {
        return supplier.get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //code A
    }finally {
        // code B
    }
}
```