# Requesting assistance to understand code snippet in Gmaps tutorial

Tags: java, android-button

Starting to do basic app development. Just doing a few tutorials atm to see if it's something I'd like to pursue further.

I'm starting with a basic google maps location tracker that wasn't too hard to find online. I so far have no errors except for the permissions alert and think it has something to do with a format of onClick method. There is some arrow between the ')' and '{' for each of the pos and neg buttons.

here is my code:

```
    final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setTitle(title)
            .setMessage(message)
/*Errors here*/ .setPositiveButton(btnText, onClick(paramDialogInterface, paramInt));
                if (status ==1)
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else
                    requestPermissions(PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
            }
/*and here*/    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", onClick(paramDialogInterface, paramInt))    {
                 finish();
            });
    dialog.show();
```

Please see below, Picture 15 of the link provided was my resource. On the culpable lines, the resource has an arrow between the ) and { end of line.
[code resource](https://www.thecodecity.com/2017/03/location-tracker-android-app-complete.html)

Comment: If you are having a hard time understanding the tutorial's code, I would suggest you to start from Java tutorial instead

Answer (score 0):

The arrow is from Font Ligature setting which basically reduces ->(dash and arrow) to the symbol shown.(Disable it from IDE settings)

Further,read this post [arrow operator in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15146052/what-does-the-arrow-operator-do-in-java) and search for lambda expressions.

Here the arrow operator allows your to skip the return keyword in an anonymous instance